# SUM query with DATETIME for CURDATE()

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get this right and I'm still working with joins, so it's likely wrong. I have 3 data tables and 1 "summary" table which is full of my submitted value id's.

I want to sum up value ID columns from 2 different tables and associate them with the current date and user. It does, but only for yesterday?  I need it to change the query to the current day.  I tried getting CURDATE() in there, but I'm clearly not doing it right.

```
SELECT U.user_name, SUM(T.cut_timetotal) AS sum_time, SUM(C.cuts_total) AS sum_cuts, DATE(S.submit_date ) AS date
FROM summary S
JOIN cut_info C ON S.cuts_id = C.cuts_id
JOIN users U ON U.user_id = S.user_id
JOIN timeT ON T.time_id = S.time_id
GROUP BY U.user_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should provide the answer you seek:

```
SELECT U.user_name, SUM(T.cut_timetotal) AS sum_time, SUM(C.cuts_total) AS sum_cuts, DATE(S.submit_date ) AS date
FROM summary S
JOIN cut_info C ON S.cuts_id = C.cuts_id
JOIN users U ON U.user_id = S.user_id
JOIN timeT ON T.time_id = S.time_id
WHERE S.submit_date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY U.user_name
```

Using

```
S.submit_date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

is better than

```
DATE(S.submit_date) = CURDATE()
```

as the former will use an index, if found, and the latter will not.

Comment: Tried that and get: "#1054 - Unknown column 'CURDATE' in 'where clause'"

Comment: I had also tried WHERE S.submit_date = CURDATE(), but I get nothing returned.  (my submit_date is set as DATETIME format).

Comment: Bingo.. that worked!  Thanks! "WHERE S.submit_date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY"